# Can't boot after apt-get update && upgrade

Tags: 14.04, boot, apt, fsck

I'm running 14.04. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which failed with an error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/
    linux-image-3.19.0-66-generic_3.19.0-66.74~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
    cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.19.0-66-generic' 
    to /boot/System.map-3.19.0-66-generic.dpkg-new': 
    failed to write (No space left on device)
```

Now, my machine won't boot. I can get to the login screen, but when I enter my password, I immediately get logged out after seeing a glitchy screen like this (sorry for the glare):

[image: img]
Trying to boot in recovery mode gives me this output:

[image: img]
 (`mountall: fsck /boot [957] terminated with status 1`)

It looks like there's a problem with `/boot`, but I can't figure out how to repair it.

I've also had trouble booting from more recent kernels, so I've been booting from 3.19.0-49.

Comment: Please log in to a TTY (press CTRL+ALT+F1 on the login screen and enter username and password) and then check your `/var/log/apt/term.log` which contains a copy of the full terminal output of your last `apt` commands. Find your last session and please copy the error and add it to your question. Let's see if that's related.

Comment: Seems like `/boot` ran out of space. Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot and reinstall that kernel update afterwards.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm in the shell in recovery mode, but `$ ls /boot` lists nothing... any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out--see my answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Byte Commander's comments, I was able to fix this using these steps:

- Open a root shell in recovery mode
- Make the filesystem writable: `mount -o remount,rw /`
- Mount the boot partition: `mount /dev/sda1 /boot`
- Configure a network connection: `dhclient eth0`
- Remove unused kernels; this took some improvising, but it was mainly a combination of `apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x`, `dpkg --force-all -P linux-image-x.x.x-x-xxxxxx`, and `apt-get install -f`.

tl;dr: don't let your boot partition get full.

Comment: Nice that you could solve your problem. Don't forget to accept your own answer after the delay of two days is over.